# No data shown in GridView when created in non Activity class

Tags: java, android, gridview, simpleadapter

When I use following code in an `Activity` class, it works fine but when moved into a separate class, the Table is drawn, but no content is shown.

```
String text[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_table);
```

I checked all variables (text, fillMaps, from to), and the correct data is available. Also if I use the standard SimpleAdapter, the result is the same.

If anybody has an idea, I would be grateful.

```
public class MainStatisticGridView extends GridView {

  public MainStatisticGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    GridView statistic = (GridView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.statistic_grid);

    String[] from = new String[]{"text"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.statistic_cell_text};

    List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String text[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_table);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("text", text[i]);
        fillMaps.add(map);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(context, fillMaps, R.layout.calendar_title_cell, from, to);
    statistic.setAdapter(adapter);

}



private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    //private variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistic_cell, parent, false);
        }

        Set<Integer> VALUES = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(
                new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20}
        ));

        if (VALUES.contains(Integer.valueOf(position))) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statistic_cell_text);
            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statistic_title));
            convertView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_intern));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure `getCount()` is present in Adapter

Comment: Android Studio is just the IDE, use that tag for issues within the IDE only. You would get the same runtime issue if you compiled from Eclipse or the command line.

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K, sorry I do not get what you mean by "Make sure getCount() is present in Adapter". What should it do?